# Populating a dict from a for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary, directory

I have a folder, containing sub-folders (SEQ1, SEQ2, SEQ3 etc.), which each containing 40 images.

I want to loop over each image, perform an operation which yields a value, then get the average of the 40 values in each sub-folder and place this value in a dict as the 'value' with the title of the sub-folder being the 'key'.

Here is what I have tried:

```
dic = {}

for (dirname, dirnames, filenames) in   os.walk('C:\Users\....'):

for keys in dirnames:
rec_3 = []


    for subdirname in filenames:

        ds = dicom.read_file(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)) #reading in DICOM images
        lx, ly = ds.pixel_array.shape  # beginning of operation
        X, Y = np.ogrid[0:lx, 0:ly]
        mask = (X - lx/2)**2 + (Y - ly/2)**2 < lx*ly/8
        st_dev = np.std(ds.pixel_array[mask]) # end of operation
        rec_3.append(st_dev)
    rec_3_avg = np.mean(rec_3)
    dic.update({keys:rec_3_avg})

print dic
```

I get the following result "{'SEQ3': nan, 'SEQ2': nan, 'SEQ1': nan, 'SEQ4': nan}"

My ideal result has the average of 40 values within each sub-folder as the value here instead of 'nan'.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that ``ds.pixel_array[mask]`` is not an empty array, because ``np.std([])`` results in ``nan``

Comment: Add some tests on the results of the operations. You should also reinitialize the rec_3 variable to an empty list before the loop on the filenames. Otherwise you are computing the average value of the files of the current directory and all the previous ones.

Comment: @Dietrich good point! it is empty, but the strange thing is, if I perform the operation OUTSIDE of the 'for keys...' loop, it works i.e. ds.pixel_array[mask] is not empty. Perhaps this means that the images are not actually being read properly, which would mean the problem should lie in the 'for subdirname...' loop not actually iterating over the images.....but that still leaves me with the question of why?

Comment: @Frodon I have performed tests on operations, hopefully my above comment explains this. Also, thank you for the rec_3 tip!

Comment: this is indeed the problem, the images are not being iterated, if I print 'subdirname' I get the following: "runfile('C:/Users/uccadmin/.spyder2/.temp.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/uccadmin/.spyder2')" - anyone know why this is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a dictionary of those values in the subdirectory first and compute the means afterwards, just a personal preference and easier to read.

```
dic_std_dev = {}
base_path = '.'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
    #print dirs
    for f in files:
        if root != base_path: #If this is a subdirectory
            ds = dicom.read_file(os.path.join(root, f)) #reading in DICOM images
            lx, ly = ds.pixel_array.shape  # beginning of operation
            X, Y = np.ogrid[0:lx, 0:ly]
            mask = (X - lx/2)**2 + (Y - ly/2)**2 < lx*ly/8
            array = ds.pixel_array[mask]
            if array:
                st_dev = np.std(array) # end of operation
                if root in dic_std_dev.keys():
                    dic_std_dev[root].append(st_dev)
                else:
                    dic_std_dev[root] = [st_dev]

dic = {}
for key in dic_std_dev.keys():
    if len(dic_std_dev[key]) > 0:
        dic[key] = np.mean(dic_std_dev[key])

print dic
```

Comment: the "if root in dic.keys():" yielding an error here, what did you mean do say ?

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be `if root in dic_std_dev.keys()`

Comment: ok this works perfectly. One last thing, any idea how to get the 'key' to be just SEQ1, SEQ2 etc, as in the dirs name instead of the root ?

Comment: you can put `dic[key.rindex(os.path.sep)+1:] = np.mean(dic_std_dev[key])`

Comment: `dic[key[key.rindex(os.path.sep)+1:]] = np.mean(dic_std_dev[key])` sorry wasn't paying attention

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this version :

```
dic = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\Users\....'):
    for dirname in dirs:
        if dirname.startswith('.'):
          dirs.remove(dirname)
    rec_3 = []        
    for filename in files:    
        ds = dicom.read_file(os.path.join(root, filename)) #reading in DICOM images
        lx, ly = ds.pixel_array.shape  # beginning of operation
        X, Y = np.ogrid[0:lx, 0:ly]
        mask = (X - lx/2)**2 + (Y - ly/2)**2 < lx*ly/8
        array = ds.pixel_array[mask]
        if array.all():
            st_dev = np.std(array) # end of operation
            rec_3.append(st_dev)
    rec_3_avg = np.mean(rec_3)
    dic.update({os.path.basename(root):rec_3_avg})

print dic
```

Comment: "if array:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: what is the purpose of the "if dirname.startswith('.'):
          dirs.remove(dirname)"  lines?

Comment: it seems as though you have some configuration subdirectories (.spyder2) in the directory you are running this in. That makes the script not iterate through those sub directories (any directory that starts with a . (e.g. /.spyder2)

Comment: @Frodon So I used array.all() and it worked..kind of, I get the following "{'C:\\Users\\uccadmin\\Desktop\\James_Phantom_CT_Dec_16th\\James Phantom CT Dec 16th\\Images\\kV_varying_recon_3\\SEQ2': 34.305334051945977, etc." - however, I only have 4 sub-folders, for some reason there is a fifth key in the dict with 'nan' as the value? Also, is there anyway to have the keys as just 'SEQ1, SEQ2' etc instead of the whole path name? extremely close to being accepted , thank you!

Comment: @Frodon the fifth dict item is "'C:\\Users\\uccadmin\\Desktop\\James_Phantom_CT_Dec_16th\\James Phantom CT Dec 16th\\Images\\kV_varying_recon_3': nan,"

Comment: @Foodaaaay: I edited my answer. Just set os.path.basename(root) as the dict key.